# Encoding: Java & Python

Tags: java, windows, python-3.x, netbeans

Having some experience in Java programming, i’ve started learning Python. The thing that struck me very quickly were massive problems in using Unicode characters in Python, compared to Java. As long as file encoding, together with the program where the code itself was written, were in UTF-8, with Java it... well, just worked. Not so in Python. I prefer coding in NetBeans, but same things happen if NotePad, for instance, is used.

Linked are 2 screenshots of [Java](http://i023.radikal.ru/1509/c9/ded95a614597.jpg) and [Python](http://s019.radikal.ru/i628/1509/68/e5a75ec5209a.jpg) showing the contrast of the problem. What is wrong? Something with the setup? Code itself? NetBeans’ Python support? Perhaps Python’s compatibility with Unicode strings as a whole?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The comment by [@eryksun](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32448437/encoding-java-python/32461377#comment52779775_32454928) has [solved the issue](http://s019.radikal.ru/i626/1509/42/74c5b9d3b012.jpg). To make Python fully Unicode in Windows, as well as in NetBeans, one have to add the environment variable [`PYTHONIOENCODING=UTF-8`](http://s010.radikal.ru/i314/1509/c9/54f4111f7cac.jpg).
Since full Unicode support in Python has been around for not quite as long as it has in Java, it’s understandable that some work to fully enable internationalization in Python is still required from the end user.

Answer (score 0):

Your image shows that you are using Python 3.4.3, which should cause no problems with unicode. How are you running it when you use Notepad?

Try calling the python code directly and let me know what happens. You shouldn't even need the `# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-` bit on top at all.

If you cannot call it directly, see if you can run that line in python directly. (Ctrl+R, open terminal by typing `cmd` then enter, then `python` and enter in the terminal.)

If it works for you, then it might be a NetBeans settings issue.

An IDE that is usually recommended for python programmers is Spyder, which is good for scientific computing. Other people do it in Eclipse or PyCharm.

Comment: The problem, as shown in the picture, is that `sys.stdout.encoding` is set to `"cp1251"` (Cyrillic), which can't encode the Latin character `"ä"`. Netbeans is probably running Python with `stdout` set to a pipe, for which Python defaults to the Windows ANSI codepage. You can override this by setting the environment variable `PYTHONIOENCODING=utf-8`. Outside of the IDE, UTF-8 in the Windows console (codepage 65001) has bugs in both conhost.exe and the CRT, so I recommend to instead use the wide-character API via [win-unicode-console](https://github.com/Drekin/win-unicode-console).

Comment: Thank you so much! It is now fully working. If you want credit for this, please post it as an answer, and i will accept it as such.